# Pass a url as a parameter with the GET methoid in the django-rest framework?

Tags: ajax, django, rest, xmlhttprequest, django-rest-framework

I am going to pass a url as a GET parameter to the restful API, but it can not match the url pattern, therefore 404 returns.

I use the django-rest framework as the server side.

Here is the `urls.py`

```
url(r'^method/?P<url>(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))$',views.Method.as_view()), name='method'),
```

And the client xhr code is something like this.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// url is like https://storage.googleapis.com/xxx/cccc/abc.txt
xhr.open('GET', 'method/' + url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        // do something
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

The regex is ok, but still returns 404 by the server.

Even though I pass the request url something like

```
xhr.open('GET', 'method?=' + url, true);
```

It still returns 404 not found.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: url like value in get parameters should be url encoded.. may be that's why ..  try that..

Answer (score 0):

Change your client xhr code like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxx/cccc/abc.txt';
xhr.open('GET', 'method/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url), true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        // do something
    }
};
xhr.send();
```